# How to generate java files from .eiq files?

Tags: maven-3, maven-plugin, emf

In eclipse PDE( with EMF-IncQuery installed), if we have .eiq file and the corresponding .genmodel file just by refreshing it generates all the .java file and puts into src-gen package.

Just wondering If we could do the same through any maven plugin??

I have gone through https://wiki.eclipse.org/EMFIncQuery/UserDocumentation/Build where got the fair idea about how to generate java files from .genmodel but no info found about generating java files from .eiq files through EMF-IncQuery maven plug-in.

PF the concerned pom.xml entry

```
<!-- Setting up generator -->
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.incquery</groupId>
              <artifactId>incquery-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.0.1</version>
              <!-- Binding execution to the code generation lifecycle phase -->
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
              <configuration>
                <!-- Output directory - required -->
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/../src-gen</outputDirectory>
                  <metamodels>
                    <metamodel>
                      <!-- Java class for the EMF EPackage - use this if generated EMF code is in the classpath -->
                      <packageClass>${project.build.directory}/../abc.def.mnq.epackage.jar</packageClass>
                      <!-- genmodel file used for generating the EMF model classes - use this if EMF model is in the same project
                       <genmodelUri>${project.build.directory}/../XYZ.genmodel</genmodelUri>  -->
                    </metamodel>
                  </metamodels>
              </configuration>
              </plugin>
        </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned documentation page has an [example pom.xml](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EMFIncQuery/UserDocumentation/Build#Example_POM.XML) that also features the incquery-maven-compiler plugin, following the 'setting up the generator' comment.

The basic idea is that you should define the output folder, and select the EPackages your code used, and then the Maven compiler will generate the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes the example pom xml has clearly mentioned about the output folder. The input in the metamodel section is not very clear to me.I have Basically the XYZ.genmodel and XYZ.ecore but DO NOT have the Epackage as mentioned the wiki page.

Do I have to create the Epackages (.java files)somehow to provide the input or the .genmodel + .ecore would be enough to generate the src-gen from .eiq files?
May be I have to dig down and provide the corresponding EPackage java files only because providing the .jar file gives  wrong classname" .error.

Comment: EMF-IncQuery expects that  the referenced EMF metamodels (EPackages) are available somehow. For this reason, the Maven compiler features two options: either reference the EMF-generated EPackage class from the classpath (basically anything you are depending on); or give a reference to the EMF .genmodel file via an uri).